# Необязательные аргументы-инстансы класса

Tags: python, функции, аргументы

Есть функция, в которую передаются 2 обязательных объекта и 2 необязательных, при этом логика функции предусматривает вызов метода класса у необязательных аргументов, которые по умолчанию выставлены как None.

При тесте этой функции в случае когда 2 необязательных аргумента не передаются ловлю очевидную ошибку:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Должна же быть какая-то механика которая позволит обойти это без try/catch?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Cow:
    def moo(self):
        print("Moo...")

# 1. Заранее подготовить объект-пустышку с теми же методами, которые не вызовут ошибку.
default_cow = Cow()

def test(a = None, b = None):
    # 2. Или создавать новый экземпляр, если он не был получен
    if (a == None): a = Cow()
    if (b == None): b = default_cow

    a.moo()
    b.moo()

test()

"""
>>> Moo...
>>> Moo...
"""
```

Можно также сделать объект прямо в параметрах по умолчанию:

```
def(a = Cow()):
    #...
```

Но надо помнить, что оно здесь создается единожды, во время объявления функции. Все дальнейшие вызовы с отсутствующим параметром, будут работать с одним и тем же объектом.